# Zend framework passing hidden field and unlink file

Tags: php, zend-framework, unlink

I am working with Zend FW and deleting images from a form submitted in a view. I successfully delete all images name from the database, each one of them in the Array using their IDs.

What I can't solve is once the names are deleted how do I unlink each file form the folder?

I have an hidden fied as follow:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Image[]" value="<?php echo $this->escape($r['image']); ?>" />
```

And I know that In the controller I can call a file name using:

```
$images = $this->_getParam('image');
```

This is fine for one image but how do I unlink an Array of files? It is the first time that I come across this problem, please help.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
foreach ($images as $img) { 
            foreach(("/uploads/thumb}/{$img}") as $file) {

        unlink($file); 
         }
    }
```

I am probably doing something silly...apologies.

Comment: I do not think that `foreach(("/uploads/thumb}/{$img}") as $file)` is valid PHP.

Comment: A suggestion might be appreciated or what it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking in consideration the help from vascowhite I managed to make it work this way. the simplest and abvious really:-

```
foreach($images as $img) { 
        $file = "./uploads/thumb/$img";
        unlink($file); 
}
```

Comment: Your answwer was very similar to mine already...anyway I have added one vote. HYH

Answer (score 1):

You use the `foreach` (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) control structure to iterate through the array. You use unlink then to every `$value` inside the loop.

It should look something like this:

```
foreach ($images as $img) { 
    unlink('uploads/thumb/'.$img);
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I have tried using it but it does not seem to work

Comment: There is no error reported. It just does not delete the files in the folder

Comment: Hi martin I have edited the question. Could you adive what I ma doing wrong? Please.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thank you for your help. Is there any chance you could have a look at a similar question?:  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723589/zend-framework-and-php-unlink-file)