# Zend Framework and php unlink file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to delete some images from a submitted form using CHECKBOX fields, plus related hidden fields to get the name of the images to unlink from file.  I am working with Zend FW and in the controller I have this:

```
  if ($input->isValid()) {
            $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->delete('Immobiliare_Model_Images i')
                ->whereIn('i.ImageID', $input->ids);

        $result = $q->execute()

 $image = $this->_getParam('Image');            
        foreach($image as $img) {
             if(isset($input->ids)) {               
             $file = "./uploads/$img";
                    unlink($file);
                 } }
```

The problem with the above code is that it unlinks all files even those the have not be checked. Also tried this:

```
$image = $this->_getParam('Image');
      if(isset($input->ids)) {  
          foreach($image as $img) {
             $file = "./uploads/$img";
                 unlink($file);
                 } }
```

Same problem: all files in the array are deleted (unlinked). If I don't use the foreach() function no file is deleted. Suffice to say that all is ok re deleting file names in database.

So my question is: How do I unlink the images where the checkbox has been checked? Thank you for your help.

The html goes like this:

```
<?php foreach($this->records as $r):?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $r['ImageID']; ?>" class="require-one" />
 <input type="hidden" name="Image[]" value="<?php echo $this->escape($r['Image']); ?>" />
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

....

Comment: The code you provided seems incomplete. `$input` is not defined. What is it?

Comment: Added the previous code that expalins the $input

Comment: Take a look around for some basic examples of using HTML Checkboxes with PHP. All the fields are returned, and are set, but they are not being checked in the code for specific values to ask if they were selected by the user.

Comment: Also, bad form to use a realtive path like that... something like `realpath(APP_DIR . '/../public/uploads')` is what i would expect assuming these are images served directly from the webserver, otherwise i would expect something like `realpath(APP_DIR . '/../data/uploads')`

Comment: @AlisterBulman I would disagree. Only checked values are sent by 99.9% of the browsers (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp). Maybe the array creation goes wrong in the first place? Please show the relevant parts of your HTML form and print_r($_POST).

Comment: I have added the basic html

Comment: @Alister Bulman: checkboxes are correctly sent because their relative id in the database is deleted. No error.

Comment: It seems like var_dump return (0) {}. But I find this very strange bacause, as said above, the records are correctly deleted from database. Am I doing something silly?